# Trouble with fontspec/unicode-math and bold upright dotless i

Tags: math-mode, fontspec, unicode-math

I'm having trouble obtaining a bold upright dotless i in math mode when using pure `unicode-math` and `fontspec`. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0.4in]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
  \Huge
  Vector $\symbfup{x}$; compare $\textbf{x}$.
  Unit vector $\symbfup{ı}$; compare $\textbf{ı}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure why this particular Unicode character is treated differently from others. Any suggestions appreciated, as long as they still use `fontspec` and `unicode-math`.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your objective(s): Should all characters in math mode be rendered upright? If so, have you considered passing the options `math-style=upright` and `bold-style=upright` to `unicode-math`?

Comment: Latin Modern Math does not have a bold version, does it? Or is bold included in maths fonts already @Mico ?

Comment: See http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math for an overview of what's currently available for `unicode-math`.

Comment: `otfinfo` shows Latin Modern Math is `Regular`. I don't see any reason to think it is supposed to support bold, even though the type1 fonts do include bold versions. But I don't know enough about Unicode maths to know it isn't somehow a feature of the regular ...

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be that symbol defined in unicode-math that I can see. There is mathematical bold lowercase iota, `\mbfiota`. or you can define a macro for U+0131 from a bold text font.

Comment: @cfr - Indeed, it appears that neither `Latin Modern Math` nor `XITS Math` feature a **bold** version of `\imath`.

Comment: as a contributor to the unicode math symbol complement, i can say with assurance that, unless a solid requirement for a symbol could be shown, it was not added.  bold letters are used to represent vectors, but the undotted i or j was expected to be used only with a diacritic, and vectors are not so embellished (to my knowledge, or that of anyone representing the unicode technical committee), so no need was seen for these letters in bold.  if you can provide a counterexample, i will take it back for consideration.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In my experience, unit vectors are normally written in bold upright text with a hat (see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector). Often the unit vectors in the Cartesian coordinate system are explicitly written î, ĵ, and k̂. This can look quite ugly when the hat is placed on a dotted i or j. (See the same reference.)

Comment: okay.  those are definitely bold.  i'll send it in.  thanks for reference.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: If there are digits in the block then why aren't there also periods and commas? I can't make bold or doublestroke or sans serif numbers like 1.2 or 3{,}14.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm curious where you'd find such constructs (where, for example, floating-point numbers in bold/doublestroke/sans serif have semantic meaning).

Comment: @Derek I actually wouldn't know where to find uses for a semantic meaning of doublestroke integers, but imho if one adds such numbers to the block then one should also add the symbols which are normally part of numbers  "+ -., "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\symbfup` (and the other `\sym..`commands) maps its argument to the `Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols` unicode block http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf. It will only work for symbols which have a target there. You can't use it for arbitrary input.

If you want to use a bold unicode character which is not in the mathematical unicode block you will have to resort to a text font. The various `\mathXX` fonts can be used for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} %to force \mathtextbf to use EU-encoding
\begin{document}

%\mathbf is possible too, but \mathtextbf is ihmo clearer
Unit vector $\mathtextbf{\symup{ı}}$; compare $\textbf{ı}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks — I didn't realize that the `\sym...` commands are actually mapping to an explicit Unicode range. Thanks for the explanation — that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Unicode specification for a mathematical bold dotless i, so `unicode-math` *cannot* provide an automatic substitution: there is nothing to point at. The character seems to have its uses (with a hat or arrow for denoting a vector/versor), but until Unicode doesn't add it and fonts are updated, `\symbfup` cannot reach it.

So, for now, `\textbf{\i}` seems the only solution, albeit ugly.

Here's a search for “mathematical dotless” in Unicode points (courtesy of UnicodeChecker)

[image]

Contrast it with a search for “mathematical small i”

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Neither the `Latin Modern Math` nor the `XITS Math` math fonts feature a bold version of `\imath` ("dotless i").

It looks like `ı` ("text-mode dotless i") is correctly mapped into `\imath` if it is encountered in math mode. And, as there is no bold version of `\imath`, `ı` and `\symbfup{ı}` both produce the same non-bold output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\boldsymbol" macro
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} 
%or: \setmainfont{XITS}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}  
%or: \setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\Huge
$\imath$, $ı$, 
$\boldsymbol{\imath}$, $\boldsymbol{ı}$, 
$\symbfup{\imath}$, $\symbfup{ı}$. 
\textbf{\i} \textbf{ı} % two forms of text-mode "dotless i"
\end{document}
```

If you load the `unicode-math` package with the options `math-style=upright` and `bold-style=upright`, you'll get the following results instead:

[image]

The characters are now upright (unsurprisingly), but the math-mode characters still are not in bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\boldsymbol" macro
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} 
%or: \setmainfont{XITS}
\usepackage[math-style=upright,bold-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}  
%or: \setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\Huge
$\imath$, $ı$, 
$\boldsymbol{\imath}$, $\boldsymbol{ı}$, 
$\symbfup{\imath}$, $\symbfup{ı}$. 
\textbf{\i} \textbf{ı} % two forms of text-mode "dotless i"
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for inserting the text-mode character as a math letter, in math mode:

```
\documentclass[border=0.4in]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareRobustCommand\mbfupdotlessi{\mathalpha\hbox{\rmfamily\upshape\bfseries{ı}}}

\begin{document}
  \Huge
  Vector $\symbfup{x}$; compare $\textbf{x}$.
  Unit vector $a \symbfup{ı} + 1$; compare $a \mbfupdotlessi + 1$, $a \symup{ı} + 1$.
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]