# How I can get bold, italic and dotless i and j in XeLaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode-math, bm

In pdfLaTeX, I can get them by `\bm{\hat{\imath}}` and `\bm{\hat{\jmath}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\bm{\hat{\imath}} \quad \bm{\hat{\jmath}}$

$\hat{\bm{\imath}} \quad \hat{\bm{\jmath}}$

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Output1]

How can I get the above results in XeLaTeX? I tried this but this doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

$\symbf{\hat{\imath}} \quad \symbf{\hat{\jmath}}$

$\hat{\symbf{\imath}} \quad \hat{\symbf{\jmath}}$

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Output2]

Using `\bm` in XeLaTeX is producing compile error. How can I get the first output? I also desire the carets or caps as in the first output.

EDIT:

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329851/trouble-with-fontspec-unicode-math-and-bold-upright-dotless-i/329895#329895)(in comments by Taiki) says that there are no bold, italic dotless i and j in Unicode. Isn't there any way to import the pdfLaTeX symbol in XeLaTeX?

Comment: Did you try `\boldsymbol`?

Comment: @marmot Yes. That too does not work.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329895/29127

Comment: @Taiki Isn't there any way to get/import the pdfLaTeX symbol here?

Comment: Indeed, there is no bold imath and jmath in Unicode. I'm really surprised and a bit angry.

Comment: @egreg -- provide a context where the bold italic undotted i and j have a distinct meaning different from the normal-weight letters and i will argue for their addition.

Comment: @barbarabeeton [Versors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versor_(physics)) that ISO norms prescribe to be in bold italic, like all vectors. Some like to denote versors with a hat. There should be dotless i and j for every math alphabet, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg -- the "versors" page shows unit vectors as upright, not italic.  i agree that there should be dotless i and j for every math alphabet, but i need explicit documentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Some expert in physics would be better than me. I'll look around.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Could you please point to authoritative sources (printed books) where that notation is used? It would be important for supporting addition of them to Unicode.

Comment: @egreg I could not find an authoritative source or any book which actually uses this. Not many people use ISO. So, this is rare. But I think that if vectors are bold and italic, then unit vectors should also be bold and italic with a caret above them to recognise as unit vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can borrow the symbols from a text font that has them, e.g. Latin Modern Roman:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\newcommand{\ii}{\hat{\textbf{\itshape\i}}}
\newcommand{\jj}{\hat{\textbf{\itshape\j}}}
\begin{document}

Unit vectors $\ii$ and $\jj$

\end{document}
```

[image: Unit vectors i and j]

(Adjust the hat position as appropriate.)

Comment: Can you suggest how to adjust the position of hat? I searched on TeX.SX but could not find how to do it.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis For example, `\newcommand{\ii}{\skew{3}\hat{\textbf{\itshape\i}}}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the legacy glyphs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{Latin Modern Math}

\DeclareSymbolFont{legacyletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{legacyletters}{bold}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\imath\relax\let\jmath\relax
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\imath}{\mathord}{legacyletters}{"7B}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\jmath}{\mathord}{legacyletters}{"7C}%
}
\newcommand{\imathb}{\bm{\imath}}
\newcommand{\jmathb}{\bm{\jmath}}

\begin{document}

$\imath\jmath$

$\hat{\imathb}+\hat{\jmathb}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to change the position of hat on j?