# Bold Italic \i without dot or i with different accent (or jmath, or other unicde symbols)

Tags: symbols, luatex, unicode-math

I use a special sans-serif font for vectors (in the provided example, Libertinus as main math font and Clearsans for the sansserif bold italic stuff). However, I am not able to access special unicode symbols. In particular, I want to access I's and j's without a dot, or even better, replace the dot with some kind of different symbol.

If I load the font for text, it works flawlessly. But using a text font inside the math environment seems not the best solution to me. So, is there any other possibility to use any unicode symbol in math mode, in this case `"0131`  and `"00EE`?

MWE:

```
%!TEX program=lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmathfont[]{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont{ClearSans Bold Italic}[range={bfsfit/{Latin,Greek},"0131,"00EE},Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathfont{ClearSans Bold Italic}[range={bfsfit/{latin,greek},"0131,"00EE},Scale=MatchLowercase]

\newfontfamily\clearsans{ClearSans Bold Italic}[Scale=MatchLowercase]


\begin{document}
vector: $\mathbfsfit{x}$ or $\mathbfsfit{i}$. 

But not working: $\mathbfsfit{\i\symbol{"00EE}}$, w/o math: \i\symbol{"00EE}?

Expected: {\clearsans\i\symbol{"00EE}}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412724/how-i-can-get-bold-italic-and-dotless-i-and-j-in-xelatex

Comment: It is `\imath`, not `\i`.

Comment: @HenriMenke that is probably a consequence of loading a text font for math (I tried it for only latin and greek). `\mathbfsfit{\i}` and `\mathbfsfit{\imath}` give the same output.